# Java import headers into header

Tags: java

In c-type languages, importing a header automatically imports all the files imported by that header. In Java is it possible to do something like - to import a file into the header itself?

Comment: What do you mean by _to import a file into the header itself_?

Comment: Java uses a classloader. It never just copies the file like in c

Comment: Moreover, Java doesn't have headers.  It just doesn't work that way.

Comment: thanks, I figured another way to do things. I meant specifically to import a package declaration so that it could be changeable in only one file rather than by refactoring.

Answer (score 6):

Java `import` statements aren't an inclusion mechanism, like an `#include` macro in C. They simple establish a short alias for a fully qualified name. For example, instead of repeating `java.util.ArrayList` or `java.lang.Math.PI` throughout your code, you can use `ArrayList` or `PI` after declaring the necessary import.

Answer (score 0):

You do dot need to import files in Java program. If the files are .java files the classes in them have access specifiers like public, private and protected.

```
private = only visible in that .java file
public = visible outside and within the package
protected = visible only within the package
```

By visible, I mean its contents and itself can be referenced in the given context.
To include other files, there are other ways for different files.
To know more visit this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm